# How to fix unresponsive bootstrap 4 card filter?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a webpage that displays cards that you can filter by title but the cards are not responding. Here's the codepen

https://codepen.io/dnorton94/pen/PoYqQvx?editors=0010

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 mb-3">
      <input type="text" id="myFilter" class="form-control" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="myItems">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">Card One</a></h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
          <p class="card-text">Some text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">Card Two</a></h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
          <p class="card-text">Some text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">Card Three</a></h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
          <p class="card-text">Some text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card Four</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
          <p class="card-text">Some text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">Card Five</a></h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
          <p class="card-text">Some text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">Card Six</a></h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
          <p class="card-text">Some text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">Card Seven</a></h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
          <p class="card-text">Some text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">Card Eight</a></h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
          <p class="card-text">Some text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>      
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, cards, cardContainer, h5, title, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myFilter");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    cardContainer = document.getElementById("myItems");
    cards = cardContainer.getElementsByClassName("card");
    for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        title = cards[i].querySelector(".card-block h5.card-title");
        if (title.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            cards[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            cards[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to be able to filter cards by title and only see the one that is typed in the search box. It's a straight forward problem and highly likely a really simple solution

Comment: ??? I typed "card t" and got 2 results: Card Two and Card Three.  that seems correct to me.

Comment: Sorry maybe too much coffee :D. I just have to figure out now why when I filter the card it stays in the same position instead of going to the first spot...I cleaned the code a bit. https://codepen.io/dnorton94/pen/NWKGagz?editors=1010